# Kubernetes CPU in nanoseconds

Tags: kubernetes, devops, prometheus, grafana, telegraf

I am trying to interpret the metrics fetched using Telegraf with the Kubernetes plugins on the k3s cluster. I see the results are reporting the CPU in terms of nanoseconds and memory and disk in terms of bytes. More importantly, I like to understand how the CPU usage shows in ns can be converted into `%`?
Below is one such example capture:

```
kubernetes_pod_container,container_name=telegraf-ds,host=ah-ifc2,namespace=default,node_name=ah-ifc2,pod_name=telegraf-ds-dxdhz, rootfs_available_bytes=73470144512i,logsfs_available_bytes=0i,logsfs_capacity_bytes=0i,cpu_usage_nanocores=243143i,memory_usage_bytes=0i,memory_working_set_bytes=25997312i,memory_major_page_faults=0i,rootfs_used_bytes=95850790i,logsfs_used_bytes=4096i,cpu_usage_core_nanoseconds=4301919390i,memory_rss_bytes=0i,memory_page_faults=0i,rootfs_capacity_bytes=196569534464i 1616950920000000000
```

Also, how any visualization tool such as Chronograf/Grafana converts these raw data in a more actionable format such as `cpu%, memory/disk utilization%`?

Thanks and any advice will help.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a running total of the number of (nano)seconds, you can look at the derivative to figure out percentages.

Example:

- At time `00:00:00` the cpu usage counter was at `1,000,000,000ns`
- At time `00:00:10` the cpu usage counter was at `3,000,000,000ns`

From this information we can conclude that during the 10 seconds between `00:00:00` and `00:00:10` the process used the cpu for `3,000,000,00 - 1,000,000,000 = 2,000,000,000` nanoseconds.

In other words, it used the cpu for 2 seconds out of 10, giving us a cpu usage of 20%.